# OnActivityResult is not called when sending data from fragment to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, onactivityresult

I send data from fragment to another activity. But onActivityResult in Activity is not called. In my fragment i use activity.setResult()

I've tried to use startActivityResult() in my fragment and still doesn't work

Here is my fragment :

```
private fun menuItemClicked(menu : DaftarMenu.Menu){
    val intentMenu = Intent()
    intentMenu.putExtra(PartDetailActivity.INTENT, menu)
    activity?.setResult(PartDetailActivity.MENU, intentMenu)
    activity?.finish()
}
```

This is my Activity:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    Log.i("requestCode MENU", " reqMenu = $requestCode")

    if(requestCode == MENU){
        val menu = data?.getParcelableExtra<DaftarMenu.Menu>(INTENT) ?: return

        Log.i("menuIntent"," menu : ${menu.id}")

        val editMenu = EditJumlahPesanan(menu, 1, "")
        editList.add(0, editMenu)
        rec_edit_quantity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Even the first Log is not called.

Please help me to get the data from my fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `activity?.setResult(PartDetailActivity.MENU, intentMenu)` should be changed to `activity?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intentMenu)`.

If after this change it still doesn't work properly, be sure to start your activity using startActivityForResult.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do you mean I change the activity?.setResult() to startActivityResult() ?

Comment: I mean when you start your new activity, don't start it with startActivity() like normal activities where you don't want a result from. Start them with a method called ```startActivityForResult()```. By using this method, your activity would be waiting for getting the result in onActivityResult() method.